How can I identify this old faucet cartridge?
I am attempting to find a replacement for this probably 30-year-old faucet cartridge. The faucet is the two-handle style, and both cartridges have rusted over the years. I was able to free up the left side with heat and gentle tapping, but the right side's stem snapped off while trying to free it up, so now I need a replacement cartridge.
There don't seem to be any identifying marks on the cartridge/stem itself, and I cannot find the maker's mark on the faucet earlier. I've tried scouring all the online cartridge and faucet catalogues I could find, but I haven't had any luck. This cartridge looked very similar, but upon finding the Danco 10472 4Z-24H/C Stem in a local hardware store, it is actually shorter than the cartridge I removed.
The cartridge seems to be 2.75" long and has 16 splines on the head. The stem fits snugly into a size C stem gauge they had at Home Depot. The length gauge at Home Depot showed it as slightly longer than a regular length 6, which I thought was odd.
Any tips on identifying this cartridge, or if anyone knows the part number, would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks!




great, now bring it to the store

@Traveler I brought it to my local Ace, Home Depot, and Lowe's, but none had it in stock or in their inventory systems. I'm open to any other advice you may have.

Are those makings on the metal part above the black part I  see ??61??

@Traveler which image do you refer to? I don't see the 61.

If you’re lucky, you’ll have a real plumbing supply place to go to. Forget the bigger stores for almost anything old.

+1 for bring it to a real plumbing supply store.

@Zach Bloomquist I know someone said this already but I can't agree more - a plumbing supply house (where plumbers shop) is the place to go for this

Looks like a fairly generic 2 3/4 inch (but need to measure!) ceramic disc cartridge for cold water.
If you google that term, you'll find a bunch of ones on amazon and places like kingston brass.  I suspect that something like a
https://www.kingstonbrass.com/products/kingston-brass-ksrp3120cc-rough
might work, but you could just buy a bunch and test them.

I ended up buying this generic cartridge that is 2.75", has 16 splines, and is type C: https://www.fdsupply.com/item/p099-19156c/2_3-4to2_15-16/ It ended up working great even though it doesn't exactly match the dimensions of the original!
